# DocuSign API emailBlurb Not Retaining Carriage Returns

Tags: docusignapi

I'm sending an envelope to the DocuSign API which includes the `emailBlurb` JSON property. I've entered several lines of text here and would like these to appear in the email that is sent to the signer with the same line breaks, however the line breaks are not being respected in the email that is received by the signer.

Here's an example of the emailBlurb JSON property:

```
  "emailBlurb": "Please sign the Contract Agreement Renewal for 2021. \r\rIf you have any questions please call us on 1800 123 456 between 9am and 5pm Mon-Fri.\r\rThe Contract Team.\rAcme Pty Ltd", 
  "emailSubject": "Please Sign the Customer Agreement",
```

and here's a screenshot of the email that is received:

[image]

You can see that it appears as one long string of text instead of like this:

[image]

Is there something else I need to do to make the email respect the carriage returns here?

Comment: Did you try  \r\n instead of \r\r ?

Comment: Also, did you try to just add a new line inside the JSON? so that you don't use \r or \n but the JSON string just goes into the next line?

Comment: I've tried using the \r\n sequence but that isn't surviving through the API - the email blurb now looks like this: `Please sign the Contract Agreement Renewal for 2021. \r\nIf you have any questions please call us on 1800 123 456 between 9am and 5pm Mon-Fri.\r\nThe Contract Team.\r\nAcme Pty Ltd`. Do you have an example of what the JSON should look like for a simple 2 line email blurb and I can maybe work backwards from there?

Comment: Actually have got it working with the `\r\n\` syntax - just had an escaping issue at my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using \r\n\ instead of \r\r resolved this for me.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer! Please check (accept) your own answer tomorrow. (I believe you need to wait a day after self-answering.) Thank you.